# Calculate counter for each month for dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have the following dataframe:

| cluster_ID | counter_1 | counter_2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 2021-01-02 10:00:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 2021-01-03 12:00:24 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2021-01-04 09:10:30 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 2021-02-15 08:10:21 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 2021-03-04 14:23:43 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 2020-12-30 13:16:45 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-01-07 12:13:23 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-06 07:28:23 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2021-01-10 14:24:23 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2021-01-15 17:23:35 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2021-01-20 13:28:13 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-11 11:23:15 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2021-04-13 21:14:19 |

I would like to define a function that generates a new dataframe that includes 2 new columns for each existing month in the table for the date column generated from the counter_1 and counter_2 information. For each group by cluster_ID, sum for each counter separately the columns counter_1 and counter_2 during each month. If no values exist for that month, the resulting table shall be filled as 0. The value of date is a Python Timestamp.

Example of the resulting dataframe:

| cluster_ID | counter_1_2020-12 | counter_2_2020-12 | counter_1_2021-01 | counter_2_2021-01 | counter_1_2021-02 | counter_2_2021-02 | counter_1_2021-03 | counter_2_2021-03 | counter_1_2021-04 | counter_2_2021-04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 |

I hope you can help me with my problem. I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert datetimes to `YYYY-MM` strings, pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='sum'`, sorting columns by dates and flatten `MultiIndex` by `map`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = (df.assign(date = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
         .pivot_table(index='cluster_ID', columns='date', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')
         .sort_index(level=[1,0], axis=1))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   cluster_ID  counter_1_2020-12  counter_2_2020-12  counter_1_2021-01  \
0           0                  0                  0                  2   
1           1                  2                  0                  2   
2           2                  0                  0                  2   
3           3                  0                  0                  0   

   counter_2_2021-01  counter_1_2021-02  counter_2_2021-02  counter_1_2021-03  \
0                  3                  2                  1                  1   
1                  3                  0                  0                  1   
2                  2                  1                  2                  0   
3                  0                  0                  0                  0   

   counter_2_2021-03  counter_1_2021-04  counter_2_2021-04  
0                  1                  0                  0  
1                  2                  0                  0  
2                  0                  0                  0  
3                  0                  3                  2
```